# Separation Proof

Tags: general-topology

I have been banging my head against this proof for a few days now, as I can visualize why it is true in my head, but don't know how to prove it in words:

Let $A$ and $B$ be nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Show that if there exist disjoint, open sets $U$ and $V$ with $A \subseteq U$ and $B \subseteq V$, then $A$ and $B$ are separated.

I've seen two answers to this proof on here, but I don't fully understand either one of them, and the question was asked so long ago that neither of those users are active on here anymore, so I can't even ask them specific questions to help my understanding. I have tried proving it directly, but immediately get bogged down in multiple cases of what $A$ looks like in $U$ while $B$ looks a certain way in $V$, and vice versa. I have also tried assuming that $A$ and $B$ aren't separated, and I can't find a way to reach a contradiction (or contrapositive) from that. I would greatly appreciate any assistance as it is the only proof from my homework that I haven't been able to figure out on my own.

Comment: How do you define “separated”?

Comment: The definition I was given is as follows: Two nonempty sets $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ are separated if $\overline{A} \cap B$ and $A \cap \overline{B}$ are both empty, where $\overline{A}$ is the closure of $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will prove that $\overline A\cap B=\emptyset$. Since $A\subset U$ and $U$ and $V$ are disjoint, then $A\subset V^\complement$. But $V$ is open and so $V^\complement$ is closed. So, and since $A\subset V^\complement$, $\overline A\subset V^\complement$. But then, since $B\subset V$, $\overline A\cap B=\emptyset$. For the same reason, $A\cap\overline B=\emptyset$.

Comment: So by assuming $x \in \overline{A} \cap B$, we are assuming that $A$ and $B$ are not separated and then arriving at a contradiction?

Comment: Also, what happened to $x$ in your proof? You start out with it, and then it never shows up again.

Comment: That sentenc with the $x$ use useless and I've deleted it. What do you think now?

Comment: I actually really like it. And I suppose you could've left the $x$ sentence in there and just made another sentence at the end saying, "This contradicts that $x \in \overline{A} \cap B$," but either way your proof helped me to make sense of another proof I saw elsewhere on this site, so I greatly appreciate your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what can you say about the complements of $U$ and $V$ and their relationships with the closures of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I believe this is what one of the other proofs I mentioned was getting at, which I did not quite follow. Since $U$ and $V$ are both open, the complement of $U$ must be closed. We know that $B$ must be a proper subset of this since it is not a subset of $U$.

Comment: Try drawing a picture showing $A$, $B$, $U$, $V$,  the complements of $U$ and $V$ and the closures of $A$ and $B$. Remember that if $X$ is closed and $Y \subseteq X$ then $\mbox{cl}(Y) \subseteq X$ and think about what this means if $X$ is given as $\overline{Z}$ for some open set $Z$.